# What are the different use cases for using REST API in java

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have an use case where i need to use rest api to call other system to get some data, as per my understanding i have created a flow of request and things which will be required. But just not sure whether it is right approach.

My UI has some input parameters based on which my rest api will fetch data from external system.

UI --> ManagedBean(Mapped to UI)-->Service Layer-->Business Layer-->Rest API Layer(i format my rest url, and other inputs required here) --> Calls MyCustomController(Implemented using SPring MVC), this will return JSON format data to the Business layer.

So whenever i call RestTemplate.executeService() --> i am calling controller to intercept this incoming request and it will fetch data from external system.

Is it right approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expose a service to your consumer then providing a web service is a better option.

Multiple ways to develop web service SOAP, REST, etc.

I find REST light weight, intuitive, easy to implement compared to SOAP.

In your case you said JSON format data to business layer. I believe you will be marshalling that into JAVA object for ease of use and good practice.

Comment: Yes Bushan my Json response is used by business layer, but is my approach good as per good practices?. And one more thing about web service is, it can be mainly used when i want to expose it to other system, otherwise i could have done same thing by calling mycustomservlet also right?

Comment: I assume your this serive is a separate app. Also when I said consumer its not just external but could be internal. This way you ca create separate logical apps and not a monolithic app. Also servlet is the underlying implementation which can be used to develop REST api.